# Creating login form in Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, authentication

I don't want to use the AuthController way of creating a login form, because I'm building a website for backend administrators. There won't be any registration needed. (That controller I will use in the future for users login and registration)

How do I actually compare the inputted login data from the form with the rows in my database?
Everything else, beside that, seems to work perfectly in my login mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

To validate a users credentials, use `Auth::attempt()`

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
{
    // redirect
}
```

Of course, the email and password are supplied by your user in the form.

You might also want to "remember" the user. That's the `attempt()` methods second argument

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)
```

Remember, you will miss out on stuff like `ThrottlesLogins` that's added to the default authentication method. But you can of course add that to your own method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` in your relevant controller.

Alternatively, use the code in the `postLogin` method of the above trait as a template to create your own authentication code.